# MEF: How to manually configure Export for a contract implementation

Tags: .net, mef

I have a MEF's CompositionContainer, a contract (say IFoo) and a module (Prism module but it doesn't matter much here, just some component).
I want in my module to register the contract's implementation (FooImpl).

If it's Unity I'd do like this:

```
unity.RegisterType<IFoo, FooImpl>().
```

That's all.
With MEF I've puzzled. I have to mark my implementation with ExportAttribute, but that lead to it'll be exported automatically. I want to manage this by myself.
Take a look at the code:

```
class MyModule: IModule {
  private CompositionContainer m_container;
  public MyModule(CompositionContainer container) {
    m_container = container;
  }
  public void Initialize() {
    ??? I want something like m_container.CreateExport<IFoo, FooImpl>()
  }
}

public interface IFoo {}
public class FooImpl : IFoo {
    //[ImportingConstructor]
    public FooImpl(ISomeService svc) {}
}
```

In Initialize I want manualy *export* FooImpl as IFoo contract not relying on ExportAttribute on FooImpl class. 
I understand that I just can create an instance FooImpl (in MyModule.Initialize above), but 
FooImpl has constructor dependencies on other component/services and I want they to be resolved on creation.

So probably I should ask: how to manually add export having a CompositionContainer instance and a contract? And then mark this export somehow as it has ImportingConstructorAttribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how MEF works by default. However, you can create your own `ExportProvider` implementation which does this, and pass it to the `CompositionContainer` constructor.

The [MEF contrib](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com) project has a few examples of [export provider implementations](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Documentation%20%26%20Features&referringTitle=Home). The [Fluent Definition Provider](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Provider%20Model%20Fluent%20Definition%20Provider) is probably the closest to what you describe. There is also an export provider which provides integration with unity.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. But I'd like to do this with already existing CompositionContainer.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [AttributedModelServices.ComposeExportedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986608.aspx).  You would use it like this:

```
m_container.ComposeExportedValue<IFoo>(new IFooImpl());
```

Comment: Here I'm loosing constructor dependencies substitution.

Comment: @Shrike: That is correct.  I believe when using ComposeExportedValue(), this causes Recomposition to kick off. Under MEF rules, when "Recomposition" happens, there's 1 negative effect: ImportingConstructors is not used.  Glenn Block explained why on his blog.

Answer (score 1):

The latest preview version of MEF has a class called RegistrationBuilder which you can use to configure your MEF parts via code.  You can get the preview version from the [MEF CodePlex site](http://mef.codeplex.com/).

Here's a [blog post with an overview of the new features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/10/27/what-s-new-in-mef-version-2-preview-4.aspx).